# Ajax error with Windows Phone HTML5 app

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an application on Windows Phone. I develop an "Windows Phone HTML 5 app".

I have a problem when I use ajax with Jquery (1.9.1).

My code is :

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://google.fr"  
    }).done(function() {
       alert('good');
    })
    .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
    });
  });
```

I have an alert "error" !

If i try with a local file (/html/test.html instead of http://google.fr) i have the same error.

if i add

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

I don't have anything ^^

How i could do Ajax with Windows phone HTML 5 app ?

Thank you ;)

Comment: What's the error? The fail function gets passed parameters that should indicate why its failed.

Comment: Try to alert more info by using this fail callback: `function(xhr, status, error) { alert('error: ' + error + ', status: ' + status)}`.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript for cross site calls is different in Chrome/ Firefox to what is required in IE.  Jquery only implements the Chrome/ Firefox version.

The answer to your question is therefore that you need to write your request in 'raw' javascript, not jquery.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm having similar issues, but only on WP7 (not WP8) and not at all in a desktop IE. Can you either give more information or some link?

Comment: According to this page http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari all use the XMLHttpRequest2 object. Internet Explorer uses the similar XDomainRequest object, which works in much the same way as its XMLHttpRequest counterpart, but adds additional security precautions. jquery uses the xmlhttpRequest2 object.  Caveat:  I learned this back when IE9 was new.  I have no idea how it applies to IE10 or 11.  WP7 and WP8 certainly use difference browser versions to each other.

Comment: Yes, but there are only very few differences (http://www.ubelly.com/2011/11/the-differences-between-ie9-on-the-desktop-and-ie9-on-wp7/). I got it to work now (problem wasn't related to this).